# Junit Test generic interface java

Tags: java, generics, junit

I want to know if it is necesary to write a JUNIT test for a generic interface, in this case i have the generic interface:

```
public interface Operable <T> {

public T suma(T ele1);
public T resta(T ele1);
public T division(T ele1);
public T multiplicacion(T ele1);
}
```

And two classes that implements that interface:

```
public class Complex implements Operable<Complex> {

private final double real, imag;

public Complex(double real, double imag){
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag;
}
....
```

and

```
public class Rational implements Operable<Rational>{
 private int numerator;
private int denominator;

public Rational(int num, int den){
    if (den==0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (den<0){
        num*=-1;
        den*=-1;
    }
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
}
...
```

I did the JUnit tests for the classes but i don't really know if it is necessary to do the test for the interface (it does nothing)

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to test about the interface? It either compiles or it doesn't.

Comment: it works, i want to know if there is a way to test that kind of interfaces or just if it's necessary to test it.

Comment: `interface`s don't provide any functionality, they're just a *contract* for any implementing classes. So it makes the most sense to test these actual classes because they provide the behaviour you want them to have. What kind of behaviour would you test for interfaces? They have none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. An interface defines a contract between a caller and a callee. A unit test should verify that an implementation of this interface conforms to this contract.

Note that if you are using java 8 and have "Default Methods" in your interfaces it means that a part of the implementation has been added in the interface. In that case these methods must be unit tested.

Answer (score 1):

The test can only suit for class, but when you write a test for a class, you can use the interface as the reference.
So short answer is no.